# Wrong operator* chosen by compiler when multiplying subtypes

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I wrote a generic Matrix class with nice operators like +, -, * in a library of my own. Especially, it has (function bodies are not important so you may ignore them but I still make a reference to it later so it's good to have):

```
template<typename T, int X, int Y>
Matrix<T,Y,X> operator*(const Matrix<T,Y,X> & left, const Matrix<T,Y,X> & up)
{
    Matrix<T,Y,X> result = Matrix<T,Y,X>::Zero;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j<Y; j++)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i<X; i++)
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k<X; k++)
                result[j][k] += left[j][i] * up[i][k];
    return result;
}
template<typename T, int Y, int X, typename U>
Matrix<T,Y,X> operator*(const Matrix<T,Y,X> & left, const U & right)
{
    // Expected to handle build-in types
    Matrix<T, Y, X> result = Matrix<T, Y, X>::Zero;
    for (int j = 0; j < Y; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
            result[j][i] += left[j][i] * right;
    return result;
}
```

Then I wrote `Matrix4x4`, a subtype of `Matrix` specialized for 3D transformations like rotations and translations, so it has member functions for that. Granted, `Matrix4x4` is a bad name, I promise I'll fix that.

At some point in the code that uses `Matrix4x4` I use `operator*`:

```
// std::vector<Matrix4x4> mstackvertices({Matrix4x4::Identity});
mstackvertices.push_back(mstackvertices.back() * m_camera.m_projectionmatrix);
```

Here `m_camera.m_projectionmatrix` is a `Matrix4x4` too.

This should call the first `operator*`, but falls into the second, as gcc gives me an errors inside the second overload, on the following line:

```
            result[j][i] += left[j][i] * right;
```

The error message:

```
Matrix.hpp|169|error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘const float’ and ‘const swegl::Matrix4x4’)|
Matrix.hpp|169|note: candidates are:|
...
```

My guess is that `Matrix4x4` not being exactly `Matrix`, but only a subtype, some rule applies that makes gcc choose the best overload that does not involve a type conversion.

I'm not sure how to fix this. I have contemplated several solutions, none of which seem good:

- Removing the operator that would receive a built-in type, thus forcing the compiler to choose the only remaining overload. This works, but forces me to remove a feature from a seemingly perfectly working library.
- Use composition instead of inheritance and overload all relevant `Matrix4x4`'s operators in terms of `Matrix`.
- Reimplement `operator*` in `Matrix4x4`. There would be duplicated code, or, if I can manage to make the call to the right overload of `Matrix::operator*` with casts, well, that would still be a hassle.
- Create `Matrix4x4::operator Matrix<float,4,4>()`. It doesn't seem to work but then I may be doing something wrong there too. Anyway I understand this would create an unwelcome copy of the object.

That's where I am now. Any other idea? Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the first place?
I'm sure I'm going to learn something out of this so any help is most welcome (:

**Edit:**

The definitions of `Matrix` and `Matrix4x4` as asked:

```
template<typename T, int Y, int X>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T data[Y][X];
    ...
};

class Matrix4x4 : public Matrix<float,4,4>
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the template parameters are, or what the definitions of `Matrix` and `Matrix4x4` look like?

Comment: Didn't think that would be relevant. Asking nicely would help anyway.

Comment: AxB multiplies with BxC not AxB.

Comment: `typename U` in the second function is deduced as `Matrix4x4 const&`, which is a better match than `Matrix<float,4,4> const&`, you'll have to restrict the types that can be used with the second function with SFINAE. Also note that the functions return a `Matrix<T,Y,X>` and not the derived class, this might not be what you want.

Comment: Yes, @Yakk. I chose to simplify the code for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Koenig operator as follows:

```
template<class T, int X, int Y>
class Matrix{
  // ...
public:
  // calculates the return value of `T*U`:
  template<class U>
  using R=decltype(std::declval<T const&>()*std::declval<U const&>());
  // maybe addin a `decay_t` to the above, if required.  (But who returns
  // a reference from binary `*`?)

  // Multiplication by a matrix on the RHS
  // The RHS dimension of this matrix, and the LHS dimension
  // of the RHS matrix, must match.  Accepts matrices with a
  // different underlying T.
  template<class U, int Z>
  Matrix<R<U>,X,Z> operator*(Matrix<U,Y,Z>const& rhs)const;
  // you can implement this operator here, or you can do it below
  // in the same header file.

  // This is the Koenig operator.  It is a friend operator that
  // is *not* a template, where the left hand side is a scalar of
  // type T, and the right hand side is our own type.
  friend Matrix<R<T>,X,Y> operator*(
    T const& lhs, Matrix const& rhs
  ){
    // implement here
  }
};
```

The member matrix multiply deals with ambiguity better than non member does.  The friend operator is what I call a Koenig operator, and must be implemented inline in the class.  You can call another function and implement that one out of line.

You could also mess around with sfinae or tag dispatching, but the above is clean and simple.  Note that scalars are only allowed on the lhs, as `Matrix * Scalar` is ... quirky.  `Scalar * Matrix` is more conventional.

Comment: Interesting! The `decltype` actually removes the wrong `operator*` : `template<typename T, int X, int Y, typename U, int Z> Matrix<decltype(std::declval<T const&>()*std::declval<U const&>()),Y,X> operator*(const Matrix<T,Y,X> & left, const Matrix<U,X,Z> & up)`. But then `operator+=` falls into the same problem, without the possibility to put decltype in the return type, since it must return the type of `this`. Also, I'm not sure how your Koenig operator helps. I didn't need it for operator*, and it doesn't help for +=. Or does it?

Comment: @gab the declryoe ssfinae is not required for the above to work.  It should work with `+=``.

Answer (score 0):

As Yakk proposed, using `decltype(Y*U)` as return type allows to remove the overloads which types can't be multiplied, thus forcing the compiler to use the correct version. As far as I understand, this is a use of SFINAE:

```
template<typename T, int X, int Y, typename U, int Z>
Matrix<decltype(std::declval<T const&>()*std::declval<U const&>()),Y,X>
operator*(const Matrix<T,Y,X> & left, const Matrix<U,X,Z> & up)
{
    Matrix<T,Y,Z> result = Matrix<T, Y, Z>::Zero;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j<Y; j++)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i<X; i++)
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k<Z; k++)
                result[j][k] += left[j][i] * up[i][k];
    return result;
}
template<typename T, int Y, int X, typename U>
Matrix<decltype(std::declval<T const&>()*std::declval<U const&>()),Y,X>
operator*(const Matrix<T,Y,X> & left, const U & right)
{
    Matrix<T, Y, X> result = Matrix<T, Y, X>::Zero;
    for (int j = 0; j < Y; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
            result[j][i] += left[j][i] * right;
    return result;
}
```

But then some operators don't have return types that can be declared in those terms, like `operator+=`. At best it must return the same type as the left hand type, `*this`. For those cases, `enable_if` can be used as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename = decltype(std::declval<T const&>()+std::declval<U const&>())>
struct can_add
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct can_add<T,U>
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T, int Y, int X>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T data[Y][X];

public:
    // ...
    template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if<freon::can_add<T,U>::value>>
    void operator+=(const Matrix<U, Y, X> & other)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; ++j)
            for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
                data[j][i] += other[j][i];
    }
    template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if<freon::can_add<T,U>::value>>
    void operator+=(const U & other)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; ++j)
            for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
                data[j][i] += other;
    }
}
```